# Plotting firebase data to ChartJS

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, chart.js, google-cloud-functions

I'm having a problem with plotting data in chartjs from firebase data. ChartJS only shows the last data in the list. I was able to turn get the object data however chartJS only plots the last and latest data on the chart.

LINKS:

[firebase database node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ni1jl.png)
[chartjs only shows the last data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yx3xr.png)

```
function gotData(data){
    //console.log(data.val());

    var records = data.val();
    var keys = Object.keys(records);

    console.log(keys);
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
        var k = keys[i];
        var sys = records[k].systolicpressure;
        var dia = records[k].diastolicpressure;
        var time = records[k].time;
        console.log(sys, dia, time);


        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: [time],
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Blood Pressure Graph',
                    data: [sys]
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero:true
                        }
                    }],
                    xAxes: [{
                        time: {
                            unit:'hour'
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You are creating a new chart every time inside the loop. You should declare an array outside the loop, populate data into that array inside the loop then use the array to populate the chart data after the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of defining the object data on every loop iteration:

```
data: {
  labels: [time],
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Blood Pressure Graph',
    data: [sys]
  }]
}
```

Try to build an array of data using the for loop, and at the end of the loop create your chart:

```
function gotData(data){
//console.log(data.val());

var records = data.val();
var keys = Object.keys(records);
var chartData = [];
console.log(keys);
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
    var k = keys[i];
    var sys = records[k].systolicpressure;
    var dia = records[k].diastolicpressure;
    var time = records[k].time;
    chartData.push(sys);
    console.log(sys, dia, time);
}

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [time],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Blood Pressure Graph',
      data: chartData
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero:true
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        time: {
          unit:'hour'
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
}
```

Hope I didn't get the parentheses all messed up :) Let me know how this works.

Comment: its still not working i had to rename the data to hey since its giving me error that data.push is not a function. Although it was been push in an array the chart cant plot its data

Comment: thank you its working my only problem now is that the latest data is the only one being plotted to the chart and i need to reverse the array because the latest time is the only one being fetched by chartjs. I need to start the array to the old time to the latest one for the array to be plot

Comment: Well I dont know what's in the sys variable, but if its a number then the chart should look good. IF it's not a number, perhaps it shouldn't be your data

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by placing an array variable outside the loop and pushing the data inside it and placing the array variable inside the chartJS data.

```
var form = document.getElementById('uidgetforchart');
var uid = form.elements.uidgetthis.value;
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
console.log(uid);

var hourOfDay;
hourOfDay = getjustHoursOfDay();

function newDate() {
  return moment().add(days, 'd');
}

var ref = database.ref('Blood Pressure Posts/Registered User/'+uid);
ref.on('value', gotData, errData);

function gotData(data){
    //console.log(data.val());

    var records = data.val();
    var keys = Object.keys(records);
    var systolicdata = [];
    var systolictime = [];
   console.log(keys);
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
        var k = keys[i];
        console.log(k);
        var sys = records[k].systolicpressure;
        console.log(sys);
        var dia = records[k].diastolicpressure;
        var time = records[k].time;
        var chartDataSys = [];
        var chartDataSysTime = [];
        chartDataSys.push(sys);
        systolicdata.push(sys);
        systolictime.push(time);
        chartDataSysTime.push(time);
        //chartDataTime.push(time);
       // console.log(chartDataSys, chartDataSysTime);
        // var datachart = {
        //     labels: 'Blood Pressure Chart',
        //     borderColor:'red',
        //     data: [
        //         {
        //           label: "My First dataset",
        //           data: [1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2],
        //         }
        //     ]
        // };

    }

console.log(systolicdata);

    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data:
        {
          labels: systolictime,
          datasets: [{
            label: "My First dataset",
            data: systolicdata,
          }]
        },
        options: {
          scales: {
            yAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                beginAtZero:true
              }
            }],
            xAxes:[{
              type: 'time',
              time: {
                format: "HH:mm",
                unit: 'hour',
                unitStepSize: 1,
                displayFormats: {
                  'minute': 'HH:mm', 
                  'hour': 'HH:mm', 
                  min: '00:00',
                  max: '23:59'
                },
            }}]

          }
        }
      });
}





function errData(data){
    console.log("Error");
    console.log(err);
}



function getjustHoursOfDay() {

    var hours=[];

    for (var i = 0; i < 23; i++) {

    var _time;
    if (i<10) {
        _time="0"+i+":00";
    }else {
        _time=i+":00";
    }

        hours.push(_time);
    }

    var lastOfDay="23:59";

    hours.push(lastOfDay);
    return hours;
}
```

Comment: Tried the same but it is not happening i'm still not getting the array data in the chart .